# Constructor and inheritance

Tags: c#

I read everywhere that :

**Constructors do not inherit from base class to derived class**

If this is true then

**How can a base class default constructor call when we create object of derived class?**

For example :

```
public class A
{
    public void AA()
    {
        //anything
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public void BB()
    {
        //anything
    }
}

class Program
{  
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        B Bobject = new B(); // Why it will call class A's default constructor if constructors not inherit from base to derived class
    }
}
```

Comment: They're not inherited, but they can (and should) still be called from child-class constructors to initialize the parent.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ace5hbzh.aspx

Comment: The default constructor is called to construct the base.  If you don't want to use the default constructor within a derived class you can use the `:base(parameter)` syntax to force calling a different constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can look into IL generated by the C# compiler. This is generated for B constructor:

```
B..ctor:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        A..ctor
IL_0006:  nop         
IL_0007:  nop         
IL_0008:  nop         
IL_0009:  ret
```

Comment: Your answer is nice but he want the reason of this, not the core of this

Answer (score 1):

The default parameterless constructor of a base class will always be called implicitly. If your base class has no parameterless constructor then your derived class must call that constructor and provide the necessary parameters.

See [Will the base class constructor be automatically called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166019/will-the-base-class-constructor-be-automatically-called)

So to answer your question no, the constructor of a base class is not inheritered, but will be called one way or another, either by your derived class constructor or implicitly when you use the **new** keyword.

Answer (score 0):

The *why*:

In your example `B` IS-A `A`, that being it is an extension of an `A`.  Given that, for `B` to be constructed the `A` bit must be constructed before `B`, otherwise `B` wouldn't be able to access and of the functionality provided by `A`.

The *how* is supplied by [Sergey Mozhaykin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26078659/442351)'s answer.

You can prove this by adding a non-default constructor to `A` (thus removing the default, parameterless one), the code will not compile because `B` no longer knows how to construct an `A`.