# How does inheritance work in this example?

Tags: c#, inheritance

What the following code does is to try and store the minimum value which would be added to the base stack inside another stack which in my example is called `s2`(and when that min value would be popped,it would also be popped from the `Stack s2`), what I don't understand is how does `base.Push(value);` in the `push` method and `base.Pop();` in the `pop` method work?

My super class is `Stack<int>` which means I can use its methods including `push` and `pop` but in my example if I use my `push` method on an `Integer` which will call the `base.Push` on that `Integer`, but where does that `base.Push` method adds that `Integer` since the only stack that I created and initialized is the `Stack s2`

```
class StackWithMin2 : Stack<int> {

    Stack<int> s2;

    public StackWithMin2() {
        s2 = new Stack<int>();
    }

    public void push(int value) {
        if (value<=min()) {
            s2.Push(value);
        }

        base.Push(value);
    }

    public int pop() {
        int value = base.Pop();
        if (value==min() {
            s2.Pop();
        }
        return value;
    }

    public int min() {
        if (s2.Count == 0)
        {
            return int.MaxValue;
        }
        else {
            return s2.Peek();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You also invoke the parameterless constructor on `base` class so it probably initializes there.

Comment: It pushes it to `this`.

Comment: Why are you creating a `Stack<int>` (`s2`) in a `Stack<int>`?

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius how's that?

Comment: Here is an explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166019/will-the-base-class-constructor-be-automatically-called

Comment: @mm8 the ```stack s2``` is the stack which will keep record of the minimum values that will be added to the ```base```,but what I don't understand is that ```base``` is used to call the methods of the superclass which in this case is ```Stack<int>``` but I never declared or initialized another stack other than s2, so where does ```base``` push and/or pop the values when I call ```base.Push(anyInteger)``` or ```base.Pop()```?

Comment: `StackWithMin2` *is-a* stack. That's what inheritance *means*. It also *has-a* another stack, `s2`. That's composition.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius is that the same case with java if I do the same and call ```super.AMethod()```?

Comment: `StackWithMin2` inherits from `Stack<int>`. By initializing an instance of `StackWithMin2` you are actually initializing two instances of `Stack<int>`. The private field `StackWithMin2.s2` and the instance of `StackWithMin2` itself. When you call `base.Push`, you are pushing the `int` onto the private storage that `StackWithMin2` gets by nature of inheriting `Stack<int>`.

Comment: Ahhh I see,thanks guys :)

Comment: @user007: From your `StackWithMin2` stack.