# Entity Framework populate entity at starting

Tags: c#, excel, entity-framework

The question was about the concept of database first or code first.
When i'm using database first, how i can check if my database is already created and filled.

Thanks

Comment: more info! we cannot read your mind...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really, you are asking two different questions. Entity Framework is not a database administration tool and as such does not have any functionality for directly loading data from a spreadsheet.

If you research each part of your question separately, you might have more luck.

[Seeding data with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312336/how-can-i-get-my-database-to-seed-using-entity-framework-codefirst)

[Reading Excel Files with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828/reading-excel-files-from-c-sharp)

Reply to comment:

```
if (!context.PostalCodes.Any())
{
    IEnumerable<PostalCode> postalCodes = ReadPostalCodes();
    foreach(var postalCode in postalCodes)
    {
        context.PostalCodes.Add(postalCode);
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Sorry :)

I have a project with entity framework database First.
when i start my application i would like that my application gets , if exist, all postal codes (this part is ok) but if not exist, my application should import all postal codes from a excel file(in my proprety.ressource) to my database.

the question is how can i check if my database is created and how can i get data from ressource directory to put them in database?

sorry for my english ;)