# Code first - database isn't created

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to make a simple project in ASP.NET, **'code first'**.

So I made a class EFDbContext:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

namespace MVCRubenWouters.Models
{
  public class EFDbContext: DbContext
  {
    public EFDbContext() : base("name=rubenwoutersdbCF")
    {
      Database.SetInitializer<EFDbContext>(new EFDbInitializer());
    }
      public DbSet<Types> Types { get; set; }
  }
}
```

And added a  connectionstring in 'web.config'

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="rubenwoutersdbCF" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLSERVER2012;Initial Catalog=rubenwoutersdbCF;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Then I created a class "EFDbInitializer to add something to the database:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MVCRubenWouters.Models
{
  public class EFDbInitializer: DropCreateDatabaseAlways<EFDbContext>
  {
    protected override void Seed(EFDbContext context)
    {
      Types t1 = new Types()
      {
        PK_TypeNr = 1,
        TypeKeuken = "Belgisch",
        TypeZaak = "Restaurant",
        Vegetarisch = false
      };

      context.Types.Add(t1);
      context.SaveChanges();
    }
  }
}
```

When I run the project and go to the SQL server management studio (and refresh), no new database is there..

Am I doing something wrong here? :/

Comment: Did you connect your Mgmt Studio to the `.\SQLSERVER2012` instance??

Comment: Try making a call to the entity framework, if there is a problem, you should get an Exception about it. Try to call this: `new EFDbContext().Types.ToList();`

Comment: @Dan Where should I put that?

Comment: @RW24 Anywhere will do, Page_Load method, whatever works.

Comment: @Dan 'An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in MVCRubenWouters.dll'

Comment: @RW24 So where is that error originating from? You really need to provide more information for us to help you.

Comment: I'm sorry. 

That error originated from the code you gave me: `new EFDbContext().Types.ToList();` 

I pasted the code in my EFDbContext class. (When I ran the project and browsed to localhost/Types, the error occured)

Comment: @RW24 You cannot put that code in the EFDbContext class, it will become a recursive call that result in the Stackoverflow exception you are getting. Put it in the `Main` program that you have.

Comment: How about connection string, set Integrated Security to SSPI.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create your database in SQL server, build your tables, then fill them using your code.

Comment: I thought that Code first meant that you create your database via code? (It's a school assignement, so it needs to be like that :/)

Comment: @user1418016 The question is related to code first, your answer doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

The way that runs on my system is force the database in Application_Start()

try this:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<EFDbContext>());
        var context = new EFDbContext("Data Source=(local);Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=myDB;");
        context.Database.Initialize(true);
```

I think the seed method is never called, To ensure set a brakpoint

You can develop your custom intializer something like below link:

[Seed in entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312336/how-can-i-get-my-database-to-seed-using-entity-framework-codefirst) and then call it in Application_Start()

```
 Database.SetInitializer<EFDbContext>(new EFDbInitializer());
```